# HTML accordion toggle icons align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a expandable list with toggle icons, i want to make the icon [in mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzIqy.png) in line in the center every time the text wrap, i had try with many way found from my search but still not working.

In bootstrap:

```
.panel-default {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
}
```

CSS:

```
.panel-heading {position: relative;}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {font-family:'FontAwesome'; content:"\f056"; float:right; color:#504371; font-size:18px;}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {content: "\f055";}
.panel-title a {display: block; padding: 10px 15px; margin: -10px -15px;}
.panel-title a:focus {text-decoration:none;}
.panel-body h3 {text-decoration:underline;}
.panel-options {position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 10px;}
h1.panel-title {font-size:18px;}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <li>
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#q1" aria-expanded="false">
        How can I get a coach ticket/invoice after booking a seat online?
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="q1" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>After buying online f you do not receive the email, you may login to membership =&gt; view booking history =&gt; select departure date, click invoice to print it out.</span> You are encouraged to print out the order summary to speed up check-in beside showing your ID. Please follow the instruction in the order summary especially about quoting the boarding code to check in into certain coach companies or waiting for the next email in the next working day to obtain an actual Ticket Number to check in into certain coach companies. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried replicating in [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/rugocorunu/1/edit?html,css,output), but failed. `:(`

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question, do you want the + button to be on its own line in the center? So it's not next to the text.

Comment: @Jeremy, yes, i dont want the button to be set "next to the text" as the button will flow up and down depends on how many line of the text is, i want it to be in the center / top right no matter how many line text is

Answer (score 0):

if you want to bring it in the middle use these classes on that div

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-5 col-md-offset-5 col-xs-offset-5">
```

this will probably work.

Comment: under which line you means? i tried to add this but it brings whole line of text to the middle instead of the icon it self

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use flex. Remove the :after for .panel-heading and add icon using ..

It would work perfectly fine

CSS

```
.panel-heading li a{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.panel-heading li a i{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <li>
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#q1" aria-expanded="false">
              How can I get a coach ticket/invoice after booking a seat online?
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>   
        </li>
      </div>
```

**Here's the Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/zpokoin/pen/xWaMdQ